# Bundling and minification technique

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I have a question regarding JavaScript bundling methodology.

We have any existing Java Web application (A product) consisting of lot of jsps. We wanted to implement the bundling and minification methodology for the js and CSS files in order reduce the overhead(). As I mentioned this is a Product it comes with its traditional web folder structure

Is there any way (Any tool) through which we  can have a dynamic bundling methodology without changing the syntax  in jsp. If we change the syntax in jsps then this will increase our  overhead during upgrade activities.

Answer (score 0):

Jawr is a tunable packaging solution for Javascript and CSS which allows for rapid development of resources in separate module files. Developers can work with a large set of split javascript files in development mode, then Jawr bundles all together into one or several files in a configurable way.

By using a tag library, Jawr allows you to use the same, unchanged pages for development and production. Jawr also minifies and compresses the files, resulting in reduced page load times.

Jawr is configured using a simple .properties descriptor, and aside of **standard java web applications** it can also be used with Facelets, Grails, Wicket and Spring applications.

https://jawr.java.net

[image]